# ADODB SQL connection in 32-bit vs. 64-bit version of MS Word

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-word, odbc, adodb

I have a MS Word document with macro code that is ~10 years old. It writes to a remote SQL Server database used across the company.

The company's computers are transitioning from a 32-bit system to a 64-bit system. Last night, some machines transitioned to 64-bit systems and started enforcing TLS 1.2 protocol, and the Word document reported an SSL security issue. It was using SQLOLEDB.

I updated the driver and the document still connects to the database on my machine (32-bit), but the Word macro is reporting "Invalid driver" on the 64-bit machines, even though they have the same driver installed for both 32-bit and 64-bit.

```
GetConnectionString = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=<server name>;Database=<database name>;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
```

Comment: When you say 64bit are you talking just about the operating system, or also 64bit Office?  I think it's typical to still run 32-bit Office on a 64-bit OS, for backwards compatibility with things that only exist in 32-bit packages.

Comment: ...the driver install "bitness" needs to match Office, not the OS.